# Set Console size & Window style

Tags: powershell

I am looking to start a script minimized, then under certain conditions override the size and colors of the console and restore/show the console. I want to revise the console first because I want the first time the user sees it to be with the revised size and colors. With the code below, if I launch from a shortcut that is set to a Normal Window then the resize works as expected. But if the shortcut is set to start Minimized, then the resize doesn't work, the window is only 120 characters wide. I have tried various Window style options; Show, Restore & ShowNormal. All behave the same way. The colors are being changed, however.
Any thoughts on what I have wrong in the sizing?

```
function Set-WindowStyle {
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 
                     'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED', 
                     'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
        $state = 'MINIMIZE',
        [Parameter()]$windowHandle = (Get-Process –id:$pid).mainWindowHandle
    )

    $windowStates = @{
        'FORCEMINIMIZE'   = 11
        'HIDE'            = 0
        'MAXIMIZE'        = 3
        'MINIMIZE'        = 6
        'RESTORE'         = 9
        'SHOW'            = 5
        'SHOWDEFAULT'     = 10
        'SHOWMAXIMIZED'   = 3
        'SHOWMINIMIZED'   = 2
        'SHOWMINNOACTIVE' = 7
        'SHOWNA'          = 8
        'SHOWNOACTIVATE'  = 4
        'SHOWNORMAL'      = 1
    }

    $showWindow = Add-Type –memberDefinition @” 
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); 
“@ -name:“Win32ShowWindowAsync” -namespace:Win32Functions –passThru

    $showWindow::ShowWindowAsync($windowHandle, $windowStates[$state]) > $null
}

function Set-Console {

    $psHost = Get-Host
    $psWindow = $psHost.ui.rawui   
    $psWindow.CursorSize = "50" 
    $psHost.Ui.RawUi.ForeGroundColor            = "Black"
    $psHost.Ui.RawUi.BackGroundColor            = "White"

    $newSize = $psWindow.buffersize
    $newSize.width = 140
    $newSize.height = 100
    $psWindow.buffersize = $newSize
    $newSize = $psWindow.windowsize
    $newSize.width = 140
    $newSize.height = 35
    $psWindow.windowsize = $newSize

    Clear-Host
}


Set-Console
Write-Host '_________1_________2_________3_________4_________5_________6_________7_________8_________9________10________11________12________13________14'
Set-WindowStyle SHOWNORMAL
```

Comment: BenH, not sure I understand. I am using user32 to show/restore the window. The problem is that the window is not properly resized. Is there some user32.dll approach to resizing the console that I am missing? And, the link is about UAC and network resources. I don't see anything there that relates to resizing the window.

Comment: I'll look into the Community Extensions, but i am still curious what is wrong with the code I have? I have found examples on line for doing the two things I want to do, but I don't know if I have implemented this wrong, or if it just isn't possible to combine them.